# How to replace the plastic socket in a B22 light fitting?

Tags: lighting

I have a broken B22 'bayonet' style light socket. One of the grooves that holds the bulb lugs has snapped off. How can I replace it, and what to look for in a replacement?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the whole thing.

Turn off power to the lighting circuit. Check, then unscrew the top white part and use a screwdriver to undo the screws holding the wires/

Any hardware store will stock replacements.

Some have metal to retain the bayonet pins, which is probably stronger than all-plastic construction.